# Casting too large a value to java short

Tags: java, integer, short

I have a java program that works with audio data.

I have the following code that takes an array of float between -1 and 1 and casts to short. I have realized that this code could maybe be broken if values outside the range of -1 to 1 are provided.

```
out = (short) ((data[i])*32768);
```

In the following code if data[i] == 2.0 , it will be too large for a short to hold. In this case would the cast just take the first 16 bits, whatever they may be, and treat it like a short?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(data[i])*32768` will result smallest type that can hold (e.g. integer here)

Then this cast: `out = (short) ((data[i])*32768)` will keep least significant bits of `short` (16 bits here, included sign bit - most significant bit aka left most bit)

You can see that if MSB is 1. The casted value will be nagative, else value with positive.

```
    int i = Short.MAX_VALUE;
    short b = (short) i;
    System.out.println(i +" -> "+ b);
    System.out.println("" + Integer.toBinaryString(0xFFFF & b));

    i = Short.MAX_VALUE + 1;
    b = (short) i;
    System.out.println(i +" -> "+ b);
    System.out.println("" + Integer.toBinaryString(0xFFFF & b));

    i = Short.MAX_VALUE + Short.MAX_VALUE + Short.MAX_VALUE;
    b = (short) i;
    System.out.println(i +" -> "+ b);
    System.out.println("" + Integer.toBinaryString(0xFFFF & b));
```

Will print

```
32767 -> 32767
111111111111111
32768 -> -32768
1000000000000000
98301 -> 32765
111111111111101
```

See 2nd test, cast value has 1 in MSB

Answer (score 2):

Java wraps the data around. What that means is that if it hits the maximum value, the next number it will go to is the minimum value. `short`'s maximum value in Java is `32767`. So if you had this snippet

```
short i = 32767;
i++;
```

The value of `i` would then be `−32768`, which is the minimum value for short.

Comment: I don't think this answer explicitly covers the example given. What if I do (short)9999999.

Comment: `(short)9999999 = -27009`. You can calculate this using modulus operations.

Comment: So what you are saying, in an indirect way, is that the cast just grabs the first 16 bits....

Comment: Kind of. It takes the 16 least significant integer bits.

Comment: @JohnKugelman you're right. I'll edit that away. It's UB for something like this, but wrap-around exists for operations between two non-overflown integers in C/C++

Comment: I can't find where the Java Language Specification _requires_ an int-to-short cast to behave that way.  Obviously, it would be very easy to implement on most hardware, but is the result of casting an out-of-range value formally defined somewhere?

Comment: @jameslarge I believe that JLS 5.1.3 (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) covers it.